# Передача поддомена как параметра в codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Как мне сделать посредством htaccess, чтобы при открытии ссылки `123.site.ru/ar/1` отображались данные с `site.ru/art/123/ar/1`, ну и чтобы ссылка сама не менялась?

Comment: Разобраться с RewriteCond и и RewriteRule и все получится)

Comment: @toxxxa а поточней? =)

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.site/? [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$2/$1/ [L]
```

Но директории должны физически существовать, можно еще сделать чтобы фронт контроллер обрабатывал, но тогда тебе нужен вот такой .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index.php$ http://site.ru/index.php?domain=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Так а зачем мне редиректы? Мне нужно, чтобы в браузере ссылка оставалась 123.site.ru/ar/1 , а вела на site.ru/art/123/ar/1

Comment: посмотрите внимательно, там редирект для домена с www на домен без www, а дальше все как вам нужно

Comment: Ну я и проверил - редирект идет с 123.site.ru/ar/1 на 
http://site.ru//ar/1/